# inserting parent and multiple child record but iam getting error

Tags: visualforce

Apex Class:

```
public class OpportunityExtn {
    public Opportunity op {get;set;}
    public List<Customer__c> cust {get;set;}
    public Boolean showOpty {get;set;}
    public Boolean showCustDet {get;set;}

    public OpportunityExtn(ApexPages.standardController std) {
        showOpty=true;  
        op = (Opportunity) std.getRecord();
        op = new Opportunity();
        cust =new List<Customer__c>(); 
        addRow();
    }

    public void addRow(){
        cust.add(new Customer__c());
    }

    public void next(){
       showCustDet=true;
       showOpty=false;
    }

    public PageReference Save(){
        insert op;
        List<Customer__c> cus = new List<Customer__c>();
        for(Customer__c c : cust){
        c.Opportunity__c=op.Id;
            cus.add(c);
        }
        if(cus!=null){
            insert cus;
        }

        PageReference pg = new  PageReference('/lightning/r/Opportunity/'+op.Id+'/view');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }

    public void back(){
        showOpty= true; 
        showCustDet=false;
    }
}
```

VF page:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityExtn" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="New Opportunity" >   
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"  rendered="{!showOpty}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!next}" value="next"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

           <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!showCustDet}" >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cust}" var="customer" >
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!customer.Name}" /> 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!customer.LastName__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Type of Customer">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!customer.Type_Of_Customer__c}"/> 
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!op}" var="opp" > 
                    <apex:column headerValue="opportunity name"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!opp.Name}" ></apex:outputText>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="back"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="save"  />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="AddCustomer" immediate="true"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

error:-

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Opportunity
>   Name, Stage, Close Date]: [Opportunity Name, Stage, Close Date]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite clear from error message itself that you need to provide all the required fields before creating the record. As you are trying to create Opportunity, You need to provide Opportunity Name, Stage, Close Date as they are required on Opportunity object for you.

Look below two lines:-

```
op = (Opportunity) std.getRecord();
op = new Opportunity();
```

You are fetching the current record form of an opportunity to be inserted using a standard controller. That's fine. But again you are creating a new instance of opportunity and hence values disappeared.

I recommend you to remove **op = new Opportunity();** from your code and it should work fine.